# Shared-Exclusive lock implementation for F#

Tags: f#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am currently working on an F# project that contains many parallel calculations. As being bound to the trimmed .Net 4  Silverlight Framework (because of the required Silverlight compatibility) I cannot use the available .Net implmenetations and may only use the Monitor object and simple locking by using the lock Keyword.

Do you have any idea how a Shared-Exclusive lock implementation for F# might be desigend best?

I did some functional programming before but haven't concentrated on doing that parallel stuff (yet).

Comment: Functional programming, doesn't that imply no side effects, such that no locks are needed?

Comment: @vstrien functional programming has several aspects, no side-effects is an aspect F# ignores almost completely.

Comment: @Ramon - But avoiding low-level lock-based code is an aspect that F# mostly follows :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what exactly you need - if you need standard mutual exclusion, then the `lock` function  is available in the Silverlight version of F# runtime.

If you need something more complex (such as multiple readers, single writer), then you can rewrite your code to use F# agents and solve the problem more elegantly. If you can add more details about the higher-level structure of your code, then someone can post an example how to solve your particular problem.

Anyway, the following SO answer shows how to write a reusable agent for multiple readers/single writer:

- [Implement CCR Interleave Arbiter in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821133/implement-ccr-interleave-arbiter-in-f)

As mentioned in the comment, you should probably try to avoid writing locks and low-level synchronization primitives explicitly, as this is a source of infinite number of bugs. F# agents give you a higher-level abstraction that is easier to use.

Comment: I agree, agents can offer a nice way of wrapping these sorts of constructs.

Answer (score 2):

Theres an excellent chapter on this in Expert F# 2.0, Chapter 13 Reactive, Asynchronous, and Parallel Programming.

See example 13.13 shows a nice Request gate, something similar may be of use.